# "IndexError: string index out of range" during the middle of the program run. from g2gtools app

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, indexing

I am running a bioinformatics software to create a custom gtf file. I am not sure how details on bioinformatics is relevant here.
I am a biologist so merely only have basic understanding of computer programs. I have been able to work out several errors, but this one makes no sense to me.

- The program runs for a while and provides a required output, but when 25% of the program has run, it give the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/home/everestial007/anaconda2/bin/g2gtools", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('g2gtools==0.1.27', 'g2gtools')

File "/home/everestial007/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.3-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 726, in run_script

File "/home/everestial007/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.3-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1484, in run_script

File "/home/everestial007/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/g2gtools-0.1.27-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/g2gtools", line 117, in <module>
    G2GToolsApp()

File "/home/everestial007/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/g2gtools-0.1.27-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/g2gtools", line 75, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.command)()

File "/home/everestial007/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/g2gtools-0.1.27-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/g2gtools", line 78, in convert
    g2gtools.g2g_commands.command_convert(sys.argv[2:], self.script_name + ' convert')

File "/home/everestial007/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/g2gtools-0.1.27-py2.7.egg/g2gtools/g2g_commands.py", line 89, in command_convert
    file_convert(args.chain, args.input, args.output, args.format, args.reverse)

File "/home/everestial007/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/g2gtools-0.1.27-py2.7.egg/g2gtools/g2g.py", line 62, in file_convert
    convert_gtf_file(chain_file=chain_file, input_file=input_file, output_file=output_file, reverse=reverse)

File "/home/everestial007/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/g2gtools-0.1.27-py2.7.egg/g2gtools/gtf.py", line 156, in convert_gtf_file
    for record in gtf_file:

File "/home/everestial007/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/g2gtools-0.1.27-py2.7.egg/g2gtools/gtf.py", line 49, in next
    self.current_record = parse_gtf_line(self.current_line)

File "/home/everestial007/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/g2gtools-0.1.27-py2.7.egg/g2gtools/gtf.py", line 101, in parse_gtf_line
    'attributes': parse_attributes(elem[8])

File "/home/everestial007/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/g2gtools-0.1.27-py2.7.egg/g2gtools/gtf.py", line 67, in parse_attributes
    if val[0] == '"':
IndexError: string index out of range***
```

I have been able to navigate to the corresponding folders, find the appropriate files, open it and locate the particular lines and messages.

1) I am not clear how and why the lines from different sub-directories related. What is the error message trying to say?

2) I am getting "IndexError: string index out of range" at the end? what does it mean? I am thinking there is something wrong with the coding in the line `if val[0] == '"':`

Comment: Something is happening to `val` which makes it any empty string. Or perhaps it's already an empty string. Why? Try this in your favourite python shell:
`>> val = ''
>> val[0]
`
You'll then get that error.

Comment: 2) The variable `val` is an empty string (i.e. `val == ''`) but the script tries to access the first character in the string by calling `val[0]`. But the variable is empty, so there is no first character. That's what the error message means.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I figured why the problem is coming but I can't see why the author of the tools had this set it up that way. The program read about 20% of the file and outputs appropriate data but its giving an error in the middle of the run. Not sure why.

Comment: I think what you have run into is a bug in the software. A situation that the original author hadn't forseen. If you are able to fix it yourself that's great! If not the standard practice is to report an issue. https://github.com/churchill-lab/g2gtools

Comment: I reported an issue to the main author. There are lots of bugs in this program and whenever one error gets fixed the other pops up. I have tried to reach the author million times but he is just too too too much ignorant.